# Rails wrong number of arguments (1 for 0), ArgumentError in SubscribeController#update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I created a subscribe section using stripe. But I am having an issue with the routing. I'm not sure whats happening or what to do. Any help would be appreciated

**Migration to User Model**

```
class AddExtraDetailsToUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
      add_column :users, :subscribed, :boolean, :default => false
      add_column :users, :stripeid, :string
  end
end
```

**Routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

    resources :subscribe

    devise_for :users do
        resources :posts 
        resources :products
    end

    get 'users/:id' => 'users#show', as: :user

end
```

**Subscribe.rb**

```
class SubscribeController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user!


    def new
    end

    def update
        token = params [:stripeToken]
        customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
            :card => token,
            :plan => 2,
            :email => current_user.email               
        )

        current_user.subscribed = true
        current_user.stripeid = customer.id
        current_user.save

        redirect_to current_user_path, :notice => "Subscription created"
    end    
end
```

**subscribe.html.erb**

```
<%= form_tag subscribe_path(1), :method => :put do %>

<article>

    <label class="amount">
        <span> Amount: $27</span>

    </label>

</article>



  <script
    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-key="<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>"
    data-amount="2700"
    data-name="Test"
    data-description="Subscription"
    data-email="<%= current_user.email %>">
  </script>
</form>

<% end %>
```

Error:

[image]

Comment: paste the error please also.........

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read the documentation of [`params`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html#method-i-params) method, you can see it doesn't accept any arguments. But you wrote as:

```
params [:stripeToken]
```

Which Ruby thinks you are passing the symbol array `[:stripeToken]` to the `params` method as an argument. As per the `params` method signature, it shouldn't accept any argument, but you are passing to it, it blows up by saying you -

```
wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
```

It should be like below :

```
token = params[:stripeToken]
```

Now in the above line `params` returns a new `ActionController::Parameters` object that has been instantiated with the `request.parameters` and on that returned object you called the method [`[]`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-5B-5D).

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful. Do you know why `subscribed` and `stripeid` is not being saved after the subscription?

Comment: If this is Rails 4.x I believe you will also need to configure [strong parameters](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters).  If you look at your logs, you will likely see that your parameters are not permitted.

Comment: @steve, does that mean I have to create a subscribe model as I dont have that and set it as `params.require(:subscribe).permit(:subscribed, :stripeid)` in the subscribed controller?

Comment: `subscribed` and `stripeid` are attributes of model User, correct?  Hopefully you have a (very good) reason that you are not handling user actions involving those attributes in UsersController (otherwise I would start there).  Otherwise, yes, you should create a Subscribe model, even if it is not persistent, and fix your naming (for instance, the subscribe controller should be called 'SubscribesController' and be in file `subscribes_controller.rb`.  Separately you should really accept @Arup's answer as he did answer your question - you can always start a new question if you get stuck on this.

Comment: Sorry I don't @Arup but if I did, you would be high on my list :)  GL